# Count word frequency without using count()

Tags: python, frequency

Python counts every character, but not word. Something to do to change? Not using count()

```
dict = {}
def convert(sentence):
    return (sentence.split())
 

sentece =  input("write something: ")
print( convert(sentence))


for item in sentence:
    if item not in ordbok:
        dict[item] = 0
    dict[item] += 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: What is ordbok?

Comment: First, you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the issues with your current logic:

- iterate on the return list you get after convert(sentence).
- if you iterate on the sentence, it will take character count

Please find the code below with the corrections:

```
dict = {}

def convert(sentence):
    return (sentence.split())

sentence = input("write something: ")
print(convert(sentence))

for item in convert(sentence):
    if item not in dict:
        dict[item] = 0
    dict[item] += 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: @victorialangoe please accept the answer if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily count anything with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

word_count = Counter(sentence.casefold().split())
```

Here, `word_count` would be a dictionary containing all words in the `sentence` and their respective counts.

Comment: Why `casefold`?

Comment: For [caseless matching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) so that the words `"The"` and `"the"` would be treated as the same word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like below:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(convert(sentence))
```

Your Whole code:

```
def convert(sentence):
    return (sentence.split())
 
sentece =  input("write something: ")

from collections import Counter
dct = Counter(convert(sentence))
```

Output:

```
write something: victorialangoe victorialangoe

Counter({'victorialangoe': 2})
```